# In R, how do I specify a set of variables to reuse in different models?

Tags: r

I want to specify a set of variables to use across different models in R. In Stata, I can write something like the following:

```
global controls c1 c2 c3
reg y x1 $controls
reg y x1 x2 $controls
reg y c.x1##c.x2 $controls
```

I can get the same result in R (I think) with the following:

```
attach(data)
lm(y ~ x1 + c1 + c2 + c3)
lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + c1 + c2 + c3)
lm(y ~ x1 * x2 + c1 + c2 + c3)
```

Is there any way in R to avoid having to paste "+ c1 + c2 + c3" for every new model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would **always** recommend using the `data=` argument rather than `attach()`, and using `reformulate()` (@WillHipson's answer using `as.formula(paste(...))` works but `reformulate()` is nicer):

```r
controls <- c("c1", "c2", "c3")  ## or paste0("c", 1:3)
lm(reformulate(c("x1",    controls), response="y"), data=data)
lm(reformulate(c("x1+x2", controls), response="y"), data=data)
lm(reformulate(c("x1*x2", controls), response="y"), data=data)
```

or even better

```r
modvars <- c("x1", "x1+x2", "x1*x2")
lapply(modvars, function(v) { lm(reformulate(c(v, controls), response="y"), data=data) })
```

or if you like tidyverse

```r
purrr::map(modvars, ~ lm(reformulate(c(., controls), response="y"), data=data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like in this [blog post](https://win-vector.com/2018/09/01/r-tip-how-to-pass-a-formula-to-lm/):

```
outcome <- "mpg"
variables <- c("cyl", "disp", "hp", "carb")

f <- as.formula(
  paste(outcome, 
        paste(variables, collapse = " + "), 
        sep = " ~ "))
print(f)
> mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + carb

model <- lm(f, data = mtcars)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I think my problem, though, is that there are more variables in the data frame than in the model. (In the first of the 3 models above, x2 is not included.)

Comment: I see, made some edits based on a blog post: https://win-vector.com/2018/09/01/r-tip-how-to-pass-a-formula-to-lm/